# Is it acceptable to make friends with a Christian at school?

Tags: christianity, school, friendship

You may all know from my previous question that I am currently in year 9 now in a top school, and the community around me isn't very Islamic.  Yes, there are Muslims here and there, but very few.

I currently have a friend who is a Christian and he isn't exactly a person who does the wrong.

As far as I know he doesn't gamble nor do Haraam acts (except for the eating of ham and the like) and is generally friendly towards Muslims like me and believes that we are peaceful people.

I don't believe I am being influenced by him in religious matters or such at all, we both have similar interests and hobbies, so we hang out quite a lot.

I try to make a good Muslim example in front of him too to show how great Muslims are such as staying away from the bad and being friendly to show that we aren't just warmongering people the media shows us to be and how Muslims can be normal people too.

I am not aiming for a scholar like life.
I am just aiming for a normal life where I can fast, pray, fulfil my duties such as zakah and not get too into politics and things having to do with extremism.

Is this friendship allowed?

As I will be spending the next 4 years of my life here in this school along with these students, and I want to at least have a friend or 2 to chat with and such or this would be the most bland times of my life.

Also, there seems to be another Muslim in my class who seems alone, I am thinking of getting closer to him as he just sits by himself in the corner these days, how should I approach him?

Comment: one of the causes of the spread of Islam, was a result of us interacting with others, the impression that other have perceived of us was what grasped their interest into our religion, therefore you are doing good by setting the example of a good Muslim and keep interacting with other of different faiths, maybe one  day inshalah they will realize this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine that being friends with non-Muslims could be haram. But of course it's a matter of interpretation as we know friends could lead you to become a better individual but also for worse! So this is a two-sided medal!

Here's my reasoning:

First of all we are asked to be good to our neighbors, and as we know the Prophet (Peace be upon him) himself had Jewish neighbors. Being good to neighbors my mean that one should visit them share his joy with them and condolence them if they have a grief one should follow their funeral etc. ... I remember even a hadith that one shouldn't let them smell what he is cocking (for example if they were poor) if they feel uneasy about that!

But i think the most clear evidence for that is ([49:13](http://legacy.quran.com/49/13)). How could people get to know each other without contact or without a relationship like friendship?

On the other hand if we as Muslims didn't know about the others and don't understand them how could we call our selves a just community ([2:143](http://legacy.quran.com/2/143)) and be witnesses over the people?

Therefore if your relationship would lead you to haram of course it could be haram, but in any other case Islam encourage you to have friendship with non-Muslims and to get to know them as this could lead them to become Muslims or at least understanding Muslims and not being afraid of them!

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 2):

Considering you can **marry** non-muslims, I don't see why not befriend them.

> "Allah forbids you not, With regard to those who Fight you not for
>   (your) Faith Nor drive you out Of your homes, From dealing kindly and
>   justly With them: For Allah loveth Those who are just.  (Quran, 60:8)"
>
> "This day are (all) things good and pure made lawful unto you. The
>   food of the People of the Book is lawful unto you and yours is lawful
>   unto them. (Lawful unto you in marriage) are (not only) chaste women
>   who are believers, but chaste women among the People of the Book,
>   revealed before your time,- when ye give them their due dowers, and
>   desire chastity, not lewdness, nor secret intrigues if any one rejects
>   faith, fruitless is his work, and in the Hereafter he will be in the
>   ranks of those who have lost (all spiritual good).  (Quran, 5:5)"

You can see more [here](http://www.answering-christianity.com/friends.htm)