# Can a Muslim be friends with kafirs?

Tags: non-muslim, friendship

I have heard that if you make friends with kafirs, you become one of them. Does a simple friendship with a Christian take you out of Islam?

Comment: Please note that your question has been asked and answered several times you may find one of these occurances among the related posts like [Is it acceptable to make friends with a Christian at school?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29794/is-it-acceptable-to-make-friends-with-a-christian-at-school?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Islam encourages kindness and respectful relationships.  Islam encourages peaceful coexistence, kindness, and understanding among all individuals, regardless of their faith backgrounds. From Quran (60:8):

> Allah does not forbid you from those who do not fight you because of religion and do not expel you from your homes - from being righteous toward them and acting justly toward them. Indeed, Allah loves those who act justly.